# Adjective for: algorithm that outputs its input if it is one of its outputs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, terminology

Is there a well established adjective or name for an algorithm such that, given as input any of its own output, always outputs it unchanged? In other words, an algorithm such that it implements a function $f$ with the property $f\circ f=f$. What would be a reference?

My application is a cryptographic security reduction. An example would be an algorithm which on input $X\in\{0,1\}^*$, outputs $1^{|X|}$.

Besides identity, an algorithm implementing $X\mapsto|X|$ in one of $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ also comes to mind.

---

*Stationary algorithm* or *circular algorithm* would do, but neither googles. In my experience that means quickly it will google here, bringing circularity to a new level!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In mathematics we would say $f$ is an [*idempotent function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Idempotent_functions). It's a widely known term and I suppose most TCS people should also recognize it.

Comment: In some contexts, this is also called a *projection*.

Answer (score 1):

Ilkka Törmä has already given the answer that $f$ is an *idempotent* function.

You might want to be aware of the concept of
[*fixed-points*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)).

A point $c$ is a fixed-point for $f$ if $f(c) = c$, and hence

$$f(f(c)) = f(c) = c.$$

A *set of fixed-points* is often called a *fixed set*.

In your scenario, the output of $f$, or
[*image*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) of $f$, is
a *fixed set* itself.

Comment: Ah. So correct me if I'm wrong, but my class of algorithms is those which output is a fixed set for them. While _idempotent algorithm_ is shorter and attested, I'm happy to have a short name for the set of outputs of these algorithms: their _fixed set_.